# How to match an interceptor to a URL without using xml in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to understand how authorization with Spring Security works. I found out that a custom filter chain can be defined by extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. But where exactly are the interceptors matched to a URL? For example, if I have something like

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()                                                                
        .antMatchers(""/signup", "/about").permitAll()                  
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                  
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

where can I programmatically decide that the interceptor for `/user/` should be `CustomInterceptor` (that extends `AbstractSecurityInterceptor`)? I do explicitly not want to do it in an xml-file, I'm trying to understand how it works programmatically.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for: https://o7planning.org/en/11689/spring-boot-interceptors-tutorial

Comment: That seems to be Spring Boot and not Spring Security in specific. Or should I extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter in Spring Security too?